# Can an "unused" object be optimized away?

Tags: c++

In code like this:

```
void foo() {
  SomeObject obj;
}
```

one might argue that `obj` is "unused" and therefore can be optimized away, just like an unused local `int` might be.  That seems like an error to me though, because unlike with an `int`, there could be important side effects of the `SomeObject` constructor.  So, I am wondering, does the language explicitly require that such local variables not be optimized away?  Or does a programmer have to take precautions to prevent such optimization?

Comment: `SomeObject obj();` is a function declaration BTW.

Comment: Compiler may optimize following the as-if rule, so if there are no side effects in constructor/destructor.

Comment: With the exception of copy constructor side effects, compilers can optimize as much as they like. However, if SomeObject() has side effects those cannot be optimized away. The object can be.

Comment: If the class has a non-trivial constructor or destructor, the optimizer probably counts it as 'used' all the time.

Comment: @Spencer: https://godbolt.org/g/S61wqo

Comment: It inlined you example's constructor and desctuctor, but that means code declared in the object is still there. Whether or not it optimized the 'object' away is a matter of semantics we could argue forever and never resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the compiler has the definition of the `SomeObject::SomeObject()` constructor and the `SomeObject` destructor available (i.e. if they're defined inline) and can see there are no side effects, then yes, this can be optimised out (provided you don't do anything else with `obj` that requires it to be fully constructed.)

Otherwise, if the constructor is defined in another translation unit, then the compiler can't know that there are no side effects, so the call will be made (and the destructor too, if that's not inline).

In general, the compiler is at liberty to perform any optimisation that doesn't alter the semantics of the program. In this case, removing an unused local variable whose constructor and destructor do not touch any other code won't alter the meaning of your program, so it's perfectly safe to do.

Comment: Even if constructor/destructor is defined in other compilation unit it still can be optimised away on link stage.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's correct the example:

```
void foo() {
  SomeObject obj; // not obj()
}
```

Second, 'as-if' rule applies to optimizers. Thus, it *might* optimize out the entire object, however, all side effect(s) of constructor(s) / destructor(s), including base class(es) must show up. This means that it's possible that you end up *not using additional memory* (as long as you don't take the address of obj), but your constructor(s) / destructor(s) will still run.

Comment: One might suggest if the object goes away, there is a good chance the function and function call could go away.

Comment: @EvilTeach: do you mean it's inlined?

Comment: I mean since there is nothing in the function, there is no need for the function, so the compiler can remove it.   With the function gone, there is no need for the code that calls it, so that can be removed too.   It's the compilers decision.   If the function really does not have effects, you wouldn't be able tell the difference if it were there or not.

Comment: @EvilTeach: yes, what you say is right, but that's only part of the scenario. Object might go away even when there are side effects (just checked this with `std::cout` in ctor and dtor. Ctor and dtor bodies are then just inlined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Modern compilers are pretty good at removing dead code (assuming you build with optimizations enabled). That includes unused objects - if the constructor and destructor does not have side effects and the compiler can see that (as in; it's not hidden away in a library).